# How to run via the code another php file

Tags: php, cron

I have some cron that run, and I have to run the file inside the cron.
now I'm using "file_get_contents();" there is a better way to run this file?

```
$qq=mysql_query("SELECT file FROM db");
while ($ww=mysql_fetch_assoc($qq)) {
  file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/'.$ww['file']);
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Set a cronjob server-side.

Or open a socket.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

it does not slowdown user's interaction

Comment: How does using a socket change things? Internally file_get_contents will STILL use a socket to do its thing. It's just a nice wrapper around the lower level network functions.

Answer (score 0):

Execute PHP within your cronjob.  Don't use HTTP on localhost to do it... you're just adding more to the process.

Answer (score 0):

File get contents is going to run file inline and return the results.  If thats what you want then that will work.

If you want to get the string and run it in place instead and have it interact with in the existing document you can use eval

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php